# regex to find inner most occurrence of strings between two delimiters

Tags: regex

I am using *TextCrawler* *regxp* to align existing plain text file. 
Text inside the file are continuous without line break.
....moredata....

,**actor's list**:

```
Amy Brenneman, Aaron Eckhart, Catherine Keener, Natassja Kinski
, Jason Patric, Ben Stiller,
```

**movies released**:

```
Gladiator,Matrix Reloaded,The Shawshank Redemption,Pirates of the Caribbean 
- Curse of the Black Pearl,Monsters Inc,
```

**genre**:

```
SciFi,Romance,Drama,Action,Comedy,Advenure,Animated,Western,Horror
```

....moredata....

I am trying to find the string(s) between the comma and the colon and replace with the same but with new line added before found pattern.
I tried following, but it matching string form outermost comma to colon.

```
[,]{1}.[A-Z].*[:]
```

Any idea on the same ? Where i went wrong?

Comment: @dev thanks for editing, but I left that content not formatted intentionally.It may confuse for pre-formatted in textfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use this pattern:

```
search:   (?<=,)[^,:]+(?=:)
replace:  \n$0
```

pattern details:

```
(?<=,)  # lookbehind assertion: only a check that means "preceded by ,"
[^,:]+  # negated char class: all characters except , and :
(?=:)   # lookahead assertion: only a check that means "followed by :"
```

Lookarounds are only tests that can make the pattern fail or succeed, they are not part of the match result.

Comment: works perfectly.let me guess whats each groups, correct me if am wrong.(?<=,)- do not start search until comma is found.(?=:) - stop once the colon is found.[^;:]-I didn't get that.And I didn't get how all other alphabets space and other characters are matching.

Comment: @kiranking: sorry, I had not seen your comment. I have added some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned pattern works:

Search Pattern : **(,?[^:,]+:)** 
Replacement String : **\n\1\n**

For eg:

Given a file a.txt with contents :

actor's list:A,B,C,movies released:D,E,F,genre:G,H,I

```
perl -pe "s@(,?[^:,]+:)@\n\1\n@g" a.txt
```

The above command produces a output of the below format :

actor's list:
A,B,C
,movies released:
D,E,F
,genre:
G,H,I

I hope the the above output is what you are expecting.

Comment: this works too.But in worst case, just for precaution how to include Alphabets and Apostrophes(') in between comma and colon.Can you suggest any reg application which explains each group so that I can learn and don't bother you quys :).

Comment: In the above search pattern, we have told to look for an optional comma (,?) followed by one or more characters so that the character is not a colon or comma ([^:,]) then followed by a colon (:). 
Hence if you want to match Alphabets and apostropes, the above regex will work.